# Can I prove that f is not a ring homomorphism using its definition - showing that any of the 2 conditions do not hold?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Can I prove that f : M_2(Z) -> Z defined by f(a b | c d) = ad-bc is not a ring homomorphism, by showing that f((a1 b1 | c1 d1) + (a2 b2 | c2 d2)) is not equal to f((a1+a2 b1+b2 | c1+c2 d1+d2)), without showing any counter example - but showing it in general.

Comment: You need a particular counterexample. Not every choice will give a counterexample, for example with $A=0$ and $B=0$ we have $\det(A)+\det(B)=\det(A+B)$.

Comment: Yeah I agree. But I meant to ask that instead of taking a particular counter example, can I show that in general f(A+B) will not be equal to f(A)+ f(B). (Using the way we do while proving them equal) There will be extra terms here in f(A+B) and hence it won’t be equal.

Comment: But it will be equal sometimes. For $A=B=0$ we have $f(A+B)=f(A)+f(B)$. You need to say exactly *when* it will not be equal. The extra terms can vanish really often.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much.

Comment: @DietrichBurde but can’t we say that the equality won’t hold for all A,B. And for the condition, it must for all A,B right?

Comment: No, we can't just say this. We need a proof, i.e., a definite proof with some choice of $A$ and $B$ such that the extra term doesn't vanish. One counterexample is enough, but you have to give one.